# ADO.NET Execution Task - Parameter Mapping Failure (Teradata)

Tags: ssis, teradata, ssis-2008

Recently the server that houses all of my SSIS packages was upgraded. This has caused a need for all of our existing packages that utalize an OLE DB connection to be migrated to an ADO.NET connection. One of the issues I am running into is that passing paramaters into the SQL Execution Task are no longer working. Even after following the instruction provided by micrtosfot [here](http://work.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx).

Before I start let me share my setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The SQL I am testing with is extremly simple. Even with such a simple statement I am receiving the following error message.

[image]

In the past if I ran into issues like this I would just set the SQL as a variable and through an expression update the parts of the statement that needs to be updated. However, the statement is over 4k characters long. Has anyone had this issue using an ADO.NET connection to teradata? If so, any suggestions on how to solve it. I have searched high/low on google w/o any luck. The most I have found is people asking the same question without any answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure - and I am sure I will be corrected if I am wrong...  But in the Parameter Mapping tab, you have @ < edw_dt_int> - I think the < and > are the issue?

Also - I assume that you just aren't showing the whole query and just showing the parameter you are trying to populate?  so you would have for example,

```
SELECT *some columns* from *some table* where *an int value* = @edw_dt_int
```

?

Comment: That is correct. The query that is actually going into this is massive. Its because of this that I cannot store it as a variable and then just perform string manipulation as an expression. The simple select in the example is one I'm testing with. I figure I'll start small and once I get that working, bring in the full query. I'll try your suggestion and post back.

Comment: So did it work out for you?  If your query is that massive - maybe you could put that in a stored procedure and that way - you have more control over the strings and stuff based on parameters you can set...

Comment: No, it did not resolve the issue I was having. In all honesty I believe the issue is caused by the outdated ADO.NET driver we are using for Teradata. In the end I created a script task in c# that performed string replacement for my variables.